# Add words for dynamic expansion to emacs mode

Tags: elisp

I'd like to add some words for dynamic expansion in an emacs mode, but I have really no idea about where to start.

Specifically I would like to add the the names of the built in functions and modules of openSCAD in scad-mode in emacs so that when I type "mi" and hit M-/ "minkowski" would be among the expansions, "dx" and M-/ expands to "dxf_linear_extrude" etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to create a dummy hidden buffer which you fill with those words (and which you put in the same major mode).  E.g.

```
(unless (get-buffer " *scad words*")
  (with-current-buffer (get-buffer-create " *scad words*")
    (scad-mode)
    (insert "minkowski otherword andyetanother")))
```